# ORDER BY Clause assistance

Tags: mysql, sql

Need a little help, I wanted to get the data from a certain table which displays entries with its unique invoice number and the date when it was Billed. however it does not accept the ORDER BY sort I needed. It force me to do a GROUP BY Clause which displays the same date for all of its result.
how do I do it?

```
select tmatter as 'Project',
tinvoice as 'Invoice #', 
tbilldt as 'Invoice Date', 
sum(tworkdol) as 'Transfer', 
sum(tbilldol) as 'Billed'

from timecard where tmatter in 
(select mmatter from matter where mclient in ('00267051'))
and
tbatch in (select bbatch from batch where bfindt between '03/02/2019' and '04/01/2019')
order by tbilldt

Project       Invoice # Invoice Date    Transfer    Billed
test proj1  6584923 3/25/2019    11,623.75   9,208.75 
test proj1  6589826 4/12/2019    4,117.50    3,417.50 
test proj2  6584924 3/25/2019    9,923.75    9,923.75 
test proj3  6582567 3/15/2019    20,099.75   20,099.75 
test proj5  6589345 3/20/2019    600.00      600.00
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL and can you provide some example schema?

Comment: This is probably the bug in older versions of MySQL, before 5.7.5.

Comment: And is this a query built by some other program? Can `matter` or `batch` return multiple results? `JOIN`s or `EXIST` would likely be much better here.

Comment: You are aggregating the last two columns with `SUM()`, while leaving the first three ones non-aggregated. In this case you **NEED** to use `GROUP BY` with all the non-aggregated columns. As it is, your query does not make sense.

Comment: You've aliased `tbilldt` as `Invoice Date`. `tbilldt` no longer exists by the time your query does an `ORDER BY`.